# Distance between two placemarks

Tags: javascript, yandex-api

I have two [Placemark](http://api.yandex.com/maps/doc/jsapi/2.x/ref/reference/Placemark.xml) objects with latitude/longitude and I'd like to get the distance between them.

Is it possible to do using Yandex Maps Api?

Or what is the preferred way of finding the distance? Using formulas/library in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Use [coordSystem.geo.getDistance](http://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.x/ref/reference/ICoordSystem.xml#getDistance) method:

```
ymaps.coordSystem.geo.getDistance(p1.geometry.getCoordinates(), p2.geometry.getCoordinates())
```